# Помогите, пожалуйста решить поставленные мне вопросы

Tags: запятые

"Понимая, что Вы получаете "Филькину грамоту", мной было принято решение, данных учащихся с 27 апреля перевести на индивидуальные задания!" 
**Кто грамотно объяснит, почему здесь не должно быть запятой?
Будут ли сказуемые однородными или составными?**

Comment: О какой запятой вообще речь? У вас одна лишняя, объясните, зачем вы её поставили - тогда будет разговор.

Answer (score 0):

Фраза безусловно нуждается в переделке, одной запятой тут делу не поможешь. Использование деепричастного оборота не соответствует грамматике, да и сама конструкция "принято решение перевести" вызывает вопросы. Это помимо орфографических и пунктуационных ошибок - о них можно будет говорить после приведения синтаксиса в норму.

Answer (score 0):

Если ставим запятую после "грамоты", то получается деепричастный оборот: 'Понимая что Вы получаете "Филькину грамоту"'. Тогда возникает ошибка в грамматике ибо
деепричастие почти всегда относится к подлежащему (а подлежащее здесь решение). Поэтому получается что "решение понимая было", а это бред.

Если не обрамляем запятыми деепричастный оборот, то он превращается в обычное обстоятельство образа действия, а не дополнительное действие. Типа как в предложении

"Сидя на стуле мною было принято решение..."

Так что да, отсутствие запятой немного меняет ситуацию. Но все же такое вольное преобразование деепричастных оборотов в обстоятельства действия слишком экстремально. Люди могут покрутить пальцем. Правильно будет:

> Понимая что Вы получаете "Филькину грамоту", я принял решение: чтобы данных учащихся с 27 апреля перевести на индивидуальные задания!
>
> В понимании что Вы получаете "Филькину грамоту", мною было принято решение: данных учащихся с 27 апреля перевести на индивидуальные задания!
>
> Учитывая что Вы получаете "Филькину грамоту", мною было принято решение: данных учащихся с 27 апреля перевести на индивидуальные задания!

В последнем предложении "учитывая" это предлог поэтому все корректно.
По запятым не ручаюсь, пусть кто-нибудь поправит.